# How to tell OS X not to "wait" during a bash script?

Tags: macos, bash, applescript

I've set up this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/Applications/NameChanger.app/Contents/MacOS/NameChanger "$@"
osascript -e "delay 1" -e "tell application \"NameChanger\" to activate"
```

I'm using it to pass file names to NameChanager. Without the second line it loads NameChanger unfocused. I thought I should use a delay and then activate with applescript to get it focused.

Unfortunately the script is "waiting" for NameChanger to run and then to exit before executing the applescript bit. How can I change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you can use the [open](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) command to launch NameChanger. This should also automatically bring NameChanger to the foreground:

```
#!/bin/bash
open /Applications/NameChanger.app --args "$@"
```

Answer (score 2):

Append a `&` at the end of commands in a shell script that you want to run in the background.

```
/Applications/NameChanger.app/Contents/MacOS/NameChanger "$@" &
```

Comment: for some reason i didn't think that would work, but it did! Thanks! While you're at it can you look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169805 I don't think it has a real answer yet. I also proposed some edits.

Comment: I'd say the given answer is accurate.